# Prove, that H(XY) = H(X) + H(Y) (entropy theory)

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, entropy

If two independent sources have entropy

> $$H\left(XY\right)=\sum _{j=1}^N\cdot \sum _{i=1}^Mp_iq_j\log\left(p_iq_j\right)$$

Prove

> $H(XY) = H(X) + H(Y)$

Comment: Is a product of random variable or a joint entropy? I am assuming joint. Then it should be written as follows $H(X,Y)$. Finally, this is a basic property of entropy which you can find in any book on info. theory.  Even wikipedia page has the answer.

Comment: Please define H(X) more precisely or how X,Y relate to M&N, is XY a number or $X×Y$

Comment: You know that $\log(a b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$, no?

Comment: Let $X=0$ with prob 1 and let $Y$ be Bernoulli $P[Y=0]=P[Y=1]=1/2$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent,  $XY$ has entropy 0, but $$0=H(XY) \neq H(X)+H(Y)=0+1=1$$ See the Boby comment on the difference between $H(XY)$ and $H(X,Y)$.

Comment: And by the way your definition of entropy is wrong; it should have a minus behind logarithm.